# C++ : How do I only look at one dimension of a 2-Dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, g++, draw

I'm writing a battleship game in the console, and I'm writing a function that will draw one grid based on a 2-dimensional array. The approach I'm taking is such:

```
--> Draw 1 row which contains a character X amount of times (like 10)

--> Draw that row, putting a newline at the end of the drawing process, 10 times to get a nice field.
```

Now, I do need to insert a newline at the end of 1 row, right? But how do I compare only the x-element of the array, and not the y-element?

Here's my code:

```
// Includes
#include <iostream> // For IO
#include <cstdlib> // For rand()

// Important game stuff
const int empty = 0; // Water
const int occupied = 1; // Ship
const int hit = 2; // Hit a ship
const int missed = 3; // Missed

// Variables
const int fields = 10;
// We want a 10x10 field
int board[fields][fields]; // board[x][y]

// Initialize board
void initb(int array[fields][fields]);
// Draw board x-axis
void drawbx(int array[fields][fields]);

int main(void)
{
    drawbx(board;)
    // game(Players);
    return 0;
}
// Initialize the board, make everything hit
void initb(int array[fields][fields])
{
    for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = hit;
        }
    }
}

void drawbx(int array[fields][fields])
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= fields; i++)
    {
        if(array[i][] == empty || array[i][] == occupied)
        {
                if(i == 10)
                    std::cout << "  X\n";
                else if(i == 1)
                    std::cout << "X  ";
                else
                    std::cout << "  X  ";
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look specifically at the `drawbx()` function. I want to draw something like

`X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X\n`

The syntax that I tried, `if(array[i][] == empty || array[i][] == occupied)`, doesn't work. There must be an expression in the second pair of square brackets. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't. Code like `array[i][]` is illegal. You must provide an index for both. Like `array[i][0]` or `array[i][1]`. Besides that remember that the index start from 0 and goes to 9.

Comment: To me it is unclear why `drawbx` shall only draw one line. But if that's what you want, you should do: `void drawbx(int array[fields][fields], int row_to_draw)` and then use `array[row_to_draw][i]`. BTW: Consider using vector instead of array

Comment: @4386427 Thank you very much. I think that will have solved my problem. Just answer it and I can flag it as an answer.

Comment: @4386427 I don't want to try to draw everything at once, since it makes my code very unreadable. I'd much rather control single elements of a row and then print that row X amount of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two major problems:

1) Array indexing is out of range. You use index 1 to 10. It shall be 0 to 9.

2) Code `array[i][] == empty` is illegal syntax. You can't leave one index empty.

If you want a function that draw one row, perhaps pass the row number to the function like:

```
void draw_one_row(int array[fields][fields], int row_to_draw)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
    {
        if(array[row_to_draw][i] == empty || array[row_to_draw][i] == occupied)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To draw the whole board:

```
void draw_board(int array[fields][fields])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
    {
        draw_one_row(array, i);
    }
}
```

BTW: Since you write C++, I'll recommend that you use `vector` instead of arrays.